# .Net applications and realtime data questions

Tags: .net, real-time, asp.net-web-api

I have a project that have many small applications and need some heart. I would like it to be Web API which need realtime data between each other.

If one application calls Web API and the other needs to listen for the data and get it in realtime, how do I make this happen?

We were talking applications that would go send data to API and need data that comes from other applications in so realtime it can get but not necessary direct answer when it call the API:

Comment: Not sure if too broad/design-y question for StackOverflow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like WCF Duplex service. Basically it is a server that is able to receive data from the clients as well as send data to clients at the same time. The clients in this case act as servers that implement a callback contract declared by your WCF service. Here is an example of how your setup could work.

WCF Service methods(Service contract):
Subscribe
Unsubscribe
PublishData

Client Callback methods(Callback contract):
SendData

When a client starts up, it first connects and provides its implementation of the Callback contract, after which it calls the Subscribe method.

When the client has new data, it submits it to the service using the PublishData method.

When the service's PublishData method is called, the service calls all of the registered client's callbacks(SendData in this case) which notifies the clients that there is new data available and lets the client decide on the way they are going to process it.